# Why do assignments to reference-type fields in .NET have all that extra assembly code?

Tags: .net, assembly, jit

Here's a simple C# class:

```cs
public class C
{
    public object O { get; set; }
    public int N { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a C# statement initializing a `C` instance:

```cs
var c = new C { O = new object(), N = 0x11223344 };
```

And here's its x86 disassembly, with optimizations enabled (retrieved through Visual Studio's "Disassembly" window):

```txt
   01A70851  mov         ecx,1654E00h
   01A70856  call        CORINFO_HELP_NEWSFAST (016430F4h)
   01A7085B  mov         esi,eax
   01A7085D  mov         ecx,73042734h
   01A70862  call        CORINFO_HELP_NEWSFAST (016430F4h)
   01A70867  lea         edx,[esi+4]
=> 01A7086A  call        7485EC00
   01A7086F  mov         dword ptr [esi+8],11223344h
```

Here's the code at address 7485EC00:

```txt
7485EC00  mov         dword ptr [edx],eax
7485EC02  cmp         eax,371100Ch
7485EC08  jb          7485EC17
7485EC0A  shr         edx,0Ah
7485EC0D  nop
7485EC0E  cmp         byte ptr [edx+33223E0h],0FFh
7485EC15  jne         7485EC1A
7485EC17  ret
7485EC18  nop
7485EC19  nop
7485EC1A  mov         byte ptr [edx+33223E0h],0FFh
7485EC21  ret
```

Here's the state of the registers just before calling 7485EC00:

```txt
EAX = 037123D4 EBX = 0137F570 ECX = 73042734 EDX = 037123C8
ESI = 037123C4 EDI = 0137F4E0
EIP = 01A7086A ESP = 0137F4C4 EBP = 0137F4C8 EFL = 00000216
```

From my understanding, the function at address 7485EC00 starts by assigning the reference to the newly created `object` (stored in `eax`) to `C.O`'s backing field (`esi+4`). That's expected. What surprised me are all the extra operations after it.

In my case, `eax` was 037123D4h, which is **not** less than 371100Ch, so the code **doesn't take** the jump `7485EC08 jb 7485EC17` and thus continues to check/set the address at `(edx >> 0Ah) + 33223E0h` to 0FFh.

Here are my questions:

- Why are there extra operations after the assignment to `C.O`'s backing field? What's their meaning?
- Why isn't it simply `mov dword ptr [esi+4], eax`, similar to assigning to `C.N` (a value-type field)?
- What's the meaning of the value at address `(edx >> 0Ah) + 33223E0h`?
- Does this happen to all reference-type field assignments?

By the way, this happens both for .NET Framework and for .NET Core, both for x86 and x64 (as checked through https://sharplab.io/).

Just to be clear: I'm not having any problem. It's just for curiosity.

Comment: It is a garbage collection implementation detail, that code updates the brick and card tables.  Very obscure, the CLR source code has been quite effectively obfuscated by a LISP programmer.  It has something to do with making a generational collector efficient, beware that's the kind of curiosity that kills cats.

Comment: Ah, garbage collection, what I suspected. But I didn't know about card tables. I found some resources online, interesting.